# Adding shortcuts to docky on Gnome 3

Tags: ubuntu, gnome3

So I have been using `docky` on Linux for a while and really enjoy it.  However, with the introduction of Gnome 3 I can still run docky but the ability to be able to drag shortcuts from the menu to the bar is now gone.  Is there another way to add shortcuts to the docky bar to get this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Just found one way out. Run the program you want to pin to dock, then it will show up on the dock then right click the icon and you will see an option pin to dock.

And let's hope someone posts a better answer.

Comment: Thanks, this does work for a few of them but but not others (like intellij doesn't start with the pinned item).